# People shouldn't be able to reject edits on their own posts without a community vote

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I [edited a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14081705) a few hours ago because the answerer made a mistake while using the editor, and it led to an error in the code (the `enter code here` sentence ended up being in the code).

The edit was rejected by the OP with the reason:

> i don't understand why my post has been downvoted

which shows that they have no idea what they're doing.

The edit was approved by two other community members, and yet, it got rejected instantly because the author rejected it.

It is obviously fine for an edit to be automatically approved by the original author, but it makes no sense for it to be automatically rejected.

Comment: `but it makes no sense for it to be automatically rejected.`?  Why?  Maybe in this one specific instance it doesn't make sense, but what about someone editing my post in a way that I don't think is appropriate.  Since the post is my own work (albeit licensed for SO to use), don't you think I shouldn't be allowed to reject edits I don't agree with?

Comment: Even if you prohibit them from rejecting the edit, if they really don't want it applied, they're just going to roll it back as soon as it's accepted anyway, so you gain nothing.

Comment: Well as soon as you publish "your own work" on SO, you agree that it is now administrated by the community, and, as such, can be edited in a way that you don't like, if 3 or 4 other people agree that it actually improves your answer.

Comment: @Servy Yeah this is true, I didn't think about that, but it would still avoid this kind of behavior.

Comment: @AntoineB But it wouldn't.   You'd still end up in exactly the same place.  You're proposing a feature that doesn't even fix the problem you're worried about.

Answer (score 3):

If someone rejects improvements to his posts he should understand that he risks getting downvotes. Now obviously in this case, the post owner doesn't understand that so I would leave a comment like:

> The suggest edit would have improved your post because of XYZ. Without it, your post has obvious flaws and may attract downvotes. Please consider accepting the suggested edit.

As Servy points out in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336844/people-shouldnt-be-able-to-reject-edits-on-their-own-posts-without-a-community#comment407134_336844) it's not useful to try to force a post author to accept an edit, he could immediately roll the change back.

So what to do if a post author refuses obvious corrections to errors in this posts? Pointing them out in comments is one common way and downvoting bad posts could be considered too.

Another way out might also be posting your own answer taking the working part of the answer of the author, giving attribution and correcting the errors for yourself. I would only recommend that if the errors are grave and if you think presenting a better solution is important there.

In this case: I would just comment (see above), maybe downvote, and move on.